# Advance Notice for Quitting After a Long Vacation?

Tags: quitting

I've worked for my current employer for about five months. I'm full-time, but hourly. I'm currently planning on quitting in about a month and a half, but I'm getting married before then and want to request a couple (unpaid) weeks off. I feel like taking two weeks off, working for a week, and then putting in two weeks' notice would be impolite, however I fear if I tell my employer now that I plan to leave in a month a half they'll want to terminate me before then and go ahead a find a replacement.

Is it better to be forthcoming now, or should I just request the time off and later give two weeks' notice?

Comment: If you've been working for the company for five months, you should have a better sense of how they're likely to react than any of us.  I really don't see how you can expect strangers on the internet to help you with this without knowing anything about their policies or culture.

Comment: Wasn't engaged five months ago. Quitting because of school. I have a good but not close relationship with my supervisor, and I don't know how he'd react, which is why I'm asking for other's opinions.

Comment: Rather not be too specific for the sake of anonymity, but it's an office job with relatively low turnover. Almost all my coworkers are salaried and many have been here for several years.

Comment: Why don't you just hand in your notice two weeks before your wedding? Unless it's a financial hardship that seems like the professional option. That said, if this was intended to be long-term resigning after 6 months isn't professional anyway and I assume this wasn't a contract gig?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it better to be forthcoming now or should I just request the time off and later give two weeks' notice?

**It is not better to be forthcoming now.**

As you suspect, there is a distinct possibility you won't be asked to return to work. One of the advantages of a short notice period is the flexibility it provides. Anything can happen in the next three weeks, and it's possible you could change your mind about leaving.

Resignation is a business decision, not personal. You are under no obligation to make things more convenient than required for your employer. Rest assured your company would feel no mutual obligation to make things easier for you.

Enjoy your wedding, take your time off, and make your decision when you get back.